# Firebase predeploy script doesn't stop on failing unit test

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, continuous-integration

I have been deploying my firebase app through a custom script in `package.json` like:
`"deploy": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false && ng lint && ng build --prod && firebase deploy --only hosting",`

This works fine but doesn't feel like the most elegant solution.
I've tried to move the predeploy scripts to `firebase.json`

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/home",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false",
      "ng lint",
      "ng build --prod"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Even though it echos that the scripts are executed, I don't see any output from `ng test` nor does it halt execution even though I have one of the test failing on purpose (the `package.json` version does neatly halt if a test fails).

How do I test my app before deploying using the `firebase deploy` command?